# Linux : How to convert media files to DVD format and burn?

Tags: video, conversion, dvd, burning, fedora-12

I have a load of media files on my PC, mostly AVI/MKV and some mpegs.

On Windows, I would use [ConvertXToDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/download-convertxtodvd.php) to convert these to DVD format, and to burn to disc. That application also lets you save a bit of space on the DVD to put the original file in its AVI format on as well.

How can I do this on Linux? What are the alternatives to this Windows application? I could try to run ConvertXtoDVD under Wine but I would prefer to find a native Linux solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.de/) is good at this sort of thing.  It's free software, available under the GPL.  I know that it works well under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ivankristianto.com/2009/06/tutorial-make-dvd-video-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

[DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) worked for me.